# Kommasetzung bei "nur wenn"

Tags: punctuation, comma

Allgemein sollte man Nebensätze immer durch Kommas abgrenzen.

> Wenn ich Zeit habe, gucke ich Fußball.
>
> Ich gucke, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.

Wenn man jetzt aus dem simplen Temporalsatz einen Konditionalsatz macht, indem man das Wort *nur* hinzufügt, dann ergibt sich ein Problem mit der Zeichensetzung.

> Ich gucke [,]nur[,] wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.

Wohin mit dem Komma? Vor oder nach das *nur.*

**Argumente für danach**

Man kann den *wenn*-Teil durch *dann* ersetzen:

> Ich gucke nur dann Fußball.

Ein Komma vor *nur* stört zumindest für mich den Lesefluss massiv.

> Ich gucke, nur wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.

Das wirkt fast wie ein eingeklammerter Einschub, während es eigentlich ziemlich integriert ist, wenn man spricht.

**Argumente für davor**

Wäre es danach, müsste der Satz mit Kondition am Anfang so aussehen:

> Nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, gucke ich Fußball.

Mir scheint, dass die normale Zeichensetzung jedoch so wäre:

> Nur wenn ich Zeit habe, gucke ich Fußball.

Vielleicht übersehe ich etwas ganz Offensichtliches, aber ...

- Wo kommt das Komma hin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dies ist ein Fall für § 74 E1 der Rechtschreibregeln:

> Besteht die Einleitung eines Nebensatzes aus einem Einleitewort und
>   weiteren Wörtern, so gilt:
>
> (1) Man setzt das Komma vor die ganze Wortgruppe:
>   *Ich habe sie selten besucht, aber wenn ich bei ihr war, saßen wir bis spät in
>   die Nacht zusammen. […]*
>
> (2) In einigen Fällen kann der Schreibende zusätzlich ein Komma zwischen
>   den Bestandteilen der Wortgruppe setzen:
>   *[…]  Ich komme morgen, gleichviel(,) ob
>   er es will oder nicht. […] Egal(,) welche Farbe sie sich aussucht, sie wird immer gut aussehen.*
>
> (3) Der Schreibende kann durch das Komma deutlich machen, ob er Wörter
>   als Bestandteil der Nebensatzeinleitung verstanden wissen will oder nicht:
>   *Ich freue mich, auch wenn du mir nur eine Karte schreibst. Ich freue mich
>   auch, wenn du mir nur eine Karte schreibst. […]*

Auf den konkreten Fall angewandt sind dementsprechend folgende Varianten auf jeden Fall zulässig:

> Ich gucke, nur wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.
>   Ich gucke nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.

Allerdings wird eine unterschiedliche Betonung auf den Kondidionalsatz gelegt (siehe auch das Beispiel zu (3) oben): Im ersten Fall sage ich erst einmal aus, dass ich generell Fußball schaue und ergänze dann, dass ich dies nur tue, wenn ich Zeit habe. Im zweiten Fall ist die Einschränkung wirklich die Hauptaussage. Mit etwas Kontext:

> Schaust Du Dir überhaupt Sportübertragungen im Fernsehen an? – Ja, ich gucke, nur wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.
>
> Wollen wir uns heute das Fußballspiel anschauen? – Nein, ich gucke nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball. Und heute muss ich noch etwas erledigen.

Offen ist, ob man Fall (2) der obigen Regeln hier anwenden kann, wonach auch die Variante mit zwei Kommata zulässig wäre:

> Ich gucke, nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.

Eine mitschwingende Betonung o. Ä. sehe ich hier aber nicht. Ich würde diese Variante höchstens einsetzen, um die Sprache von jemandem wiederzugeben, der sowohl vor als auch nach *nur* eine größere Pause lässt.

Comment: "Nein, ich gucke nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball. Und heute muss ich noch etwas erledigen." -> Besagt nicht ganz, was du hier ausdrücken möchtest. Die Variante, wie sie in der Antwort steht besagt: "Ich gucke nur Fußball, aber nur wenn ich Zeit habe." Das ist nicht was du ausdrücken willst. Dies ist eine Antwort auf die Frage "Guckst du Hockey? Nein, nur Fußball, wenn ich Zeit habe." Im Kontext willst du aber sagen, "Ich guck nur dann Fußball, wenn ich Zeit habe."

Comment: Das mit den zwei Kommas versteh ich übrigens gar nicht. Meines Erachtens ist das definitiv falsch, aber vielleicht sehe ich da etwas nicht...

Comment: "Wollen wir uns heute das Fußballspiel anschauen? – Nein, ich gucke nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball." -- Das Beispiel wäre klarer, wenn du "Handballspiel" benutztest. Denn dieser Satz sagt, dass der Mensch ausschließlich Fußball schaut.

Comment: @Em1: Ich vermute mal, dass uns unterschiedliche Betonungen des Satzes vorschweben. Wenn ich sagen wollte, dass Fußball die einzige Sportart sei, die ich gucke, wäre der Satz (»Nein, ich gucke nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.«) zwar prinzipiell denkbar, aber so ungünstig strukturiert, dass ich nicht erwarten kann, dass er in geschriebener Sprache verstanden wird. Ich gehe hier von einer ähnlichen Betonungsstruktur wie in »Ich lese *nur,* wenn ich Zeit habe.« oder »Er lief *so,* dass er immer in Sichtweite blieb.« aus.

Comment: @Em1: Was die Korrektheit der Variante mit zwei Kommata betrifft: Regel (2) ließe sie nun mal zu, ist aber maximal schwammig, was ihren Gültigkeitsbereich betrifft. Mehr kann ich auch nicht wiedergeben.

Comment: Wenn die Betonungsstruktur identisch ist zu "Ich lese nur, wenn ich Zeit habe", dann ist dein Komma falsch gesetzt und somit dein Satz falsch.

Comment: @Em1: Kannst Du das näher erläutern?

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, beide Sätze ließen sich wie folgt umformen, um die Bedeutung zu verdeutlichen:

> Ich gucke, nur wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball. => Nur wenn ich Zeit habe, gucke ich Fußball.
>
> Ich gucke nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball. => Wenn ich Zeit habe, gucke ich nur Fußball.

Genau genommen ist die zweite Variante kein "nur wenn", sondern ein "nur Fußball".

Die Variante mit jeweils einem Komma vor und nach "nur" kommt mir falsch vor.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Ich gucke nur, wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.
>   2 Ich gucke, nur wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.

Satz 2 ist ganz OK. Man könnte überlegen, Gedankenstrichen zu verwenden, da es imho eher einem Gedankeneinschub näher kommt, aber man kann es so belassen.

Satz 1 jedoch ist eine kleine Katastrophe. Und besagt was ganz anderes, als viele denken.

Eliminieren wir erstmal den Nebensatz und betrachten den Hauptsatz an sich: "Ich gucke nur Fußball". Dieser besagt, dass du keinen anderen Sport schaust.

Das *nur* erhält jedoch eine ganz andere Bedeutung, wenn der Nebensatz "wenn ich Zeit habe" angeschlossen wird. Dann besagt der Satz, dass du nur dann Fußball schaust, wenn du Zeit hast. Ob du anderen Sport schaust, steht nicht mehr zur Diskussion.

Möchtest du jedoch aussagen, dass du nur Fußball guckst und nur wenn du Zeit hast, hast du zwei Möglichkeiten. Die eindeutlichere ist:

> Ich schaue nur Fußball, aber auch nur dann, wenn ich Zeit habe.

Und die "schlechtere" ist genau dein Beispiel:

> Ich gucke nur, (und auch nur) wenn ich Zeit habe, Fußball.

Hier sind sind Gedankenstriche definitiv besser, da dies zweifelfrei ein gedanklicher Einschub ist und den Satzfluß vollständig unterbricht. Außerdem wird es dann erst wirklich ersichtlich, dass das *nur* keine Relation mehr zum Einschub hat.

Satz 2 ist wie eingangs erwähnt soweit schon korrekt. Es gibt natürlich auch hier mehrere Möglichkeiten, um dasselbe auszudrücken:

> Nur wenn ich Zeit habe, gucke ich Fußball.
>   Ich gucke Fußball, aber nur (dann), wenn ich Zeit habe.

Comment: Also für mich ist Satz 1 inhaltlich das Equivalent zu "Ich gucke nur Fußball, wenn ich..." und "Fußball guck ich nur, wenn ich Zeit habe." Das nur hat nix mit Fußball zu tun.

Comment: @Emanuel Setze Gedankenstriche ein, dann wirds deutlich: "Ich gucke nur–wenn ich Zeit habe–Fußball." Aussage: Ich gucke nur Fußball. Randnotiz: Außerdem nur dann, wenn ich Zeit habe.

Comment: Mir geht es um die Punktierung des ganz normal dahingesagten Satzes "Ich gucke nur wenn ich Zeit habe Fußball." Da sind Gedankenstriche gerade genau fehl am Platz, da die Information mitnichten eine Randnotiz ist, sondern die Hauptsache. Und ich glaube, dass jeder den Satz ohne spezielle Betonung genauso versteht, wie ich ihn meine. "Wann guckst du Fußball?" "Nur wenn ich Zeit hab"

Comment: Ich kann Dein Problem mit Satz 1 nicht nachvollziehen. Nicht in jedem Fall muss im Deutschen ein Hauptsatz noch Sinn ergeben, wenn ein Nebensatz entfernt wird.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Hab ich doch nie behauptet... Oder anders: Ich hab nicht mal ein Wort darüber verloren.

Comment: Mir geht es (vielleicht) wie @Wrzlprmft. Warum Satz 1 eine "kleine Katastrophe" sein soll, erschließt sich mir aus der Antwort nicht, und ich kann die Argumentation, die vom Weglassen des Hauptsatzes ausgeht, nicht nachvollziehen. Ich finde zwar, der zweite Satz in Wrzlprmfts Kommentar hat damit nichts zu tun, aber das ändert nichts am Kern des Problems.