# Translation of “such that”: “so, dass”?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, conjunction, comma

Consider the following english sentence:

> A function *f: A → B* is called surjective if for every *b* in *B*, there is some *a* in *A* such that *f(a) = b.*

What is the German translation of this sentence? In particular, I am interested in the German translation of the *such that*-part.

Which of the following translations is correct and which are false?

> Eine Funktion *f: A → B* heißt surjektiv, wenn es für alle *b* in *B* ein *a* in *A* gibt …
>
> 1. … derart, dass *f(a) = b.*
> 2. … so, dass *f(a) = b.*
> 3. …, sodass *f(a) = b.*
> 4. …, so dass *f(a) = b.*
> 5. … so dass *f(a) = b.*

Intuitively, I would claim that 1 and 2 are correct and the others false. But I have also seen the other options used, that is why I am wondering.

Comment: Related: [Difference between “so dass” and “sodass”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/17813/2594)

Comment: option 1 for sure is correct, but I would consider it "old-fashioned". Option 2 really sounds strange to me, because you would stop after "so" and take a breath - sounds totally unnatural.

Answer (score 10):

Mathematicians usually say /zoˈdas/ in this context, i.e., they put
the stress on "dass", pronounce "so" with a short vowel, and don't make
any pause between /zo/ and /das/. That means that they use the
conjunction "sodass", which can also be written as "so dass" according
to the official spelling rules. In this case, the comma is put before
the entire conjunction, which means that options 3 and 4 are correct:

> Es existiert ein a in A, so dass f(a) = b.
>
> Es existiert ein a in A, sodass f(a) = b.

It is possible, but less common, to stress "so", as in

> Schreib so, dass man dich versteht.

Now there is pause before "dass", and "so" tends to be long,
i.e., /ˈzoː das/. In this case, the conjunction is just "dass", and therefore
the comma comes between "so" and "dass", that is, option 2.

Option 1 is of course also possible, but this is also less commonly used.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the easy ones, (5) is wrong. For the moment I will regard (3) and (4) as equivalent and use only (4).

Now “derart, dass” is correct, precise, albeit a bit old-fashioned. Therefore, “so, dass” should be just as correct. However, “..., so dass” is used much more commonly, and it also fits how the phrase is usually spoken in mathematics. Therefore this also has to be seen as correct.

Now there is a certain discrepancy between this use of “..., so dass” and the usual meaning. Indeed it could be argued that version (4) should mean the following.

> Eine Funktion *f: A → B* heißt surjektiv, wenn es für jedes *b* aus *B* ein *a* in *A* gibt. Daraus folgt dann auch, dass *f(a) = b.*

This is of course nonsensical.

One might therefore assume that the use of “..., so dass” is a modern sloppiness, perhaps influenced by English. To see if it is indeed new, I have looked for the phrase in van der Waerden's “Algebra I”. However, I have only the eighth edition at hand, which is from 1971. While defining an isomorphism, the author writes the following. (I have changed $\bar a$ into $a'$ for typesetting reasons and also not tried to reproduce the fraktur font for sets. The **emphasis** is mine.)

> Wenn es nun möglich ist, die beiden Mengen eineindeutig aufeinander abzubilden **derart, daß** die Relationen bei der Abbildung erhalten bleiben, d.h. wenn jedem Element *a* von *M* umkehrbar eindeutig ein Element *a'* von *M'* zugeordnet werden kann, **so daß** die Relationen, die zwischen irgendwelchen Elementen *a*, *b*, ... von *M* bestehen, auch zwischen den zugeordneten Elementen *a'*, *b'*, ... bestehen und umgekehrt, so nennt man die beiden Mengen *isomorph* [...].

We see that while the good old (1) is used, (4) is also used. This has helped me to lay my qualms about it to rest. (Even though the 1930 edition was suspiciously titled “Moderne Algebra”.)

Now finally, it seems that nowadays “sodass” is preferred over “so dass” as has been explained in [an answer to a different question](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/17813/3237). It could again be argued that this favours the above nonsensical reading of the sentence, but it seems that official grammar or spelling do not take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

Im Duden (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sodass) steht, dass "sodass" bzw. "so dass" folgende Bedeutung hat:

> mit dem Ergebnis, der Folge; und das hatte zur Folge

Die Varianten

> Es existiert ein a in A, so dass f(a) = b.
>
> Es existiert ein a in A, sodass f(a) = b.

sind also falsch, da f(a) = b keine Folge davon ist, dass ein a in A existiert.

"such that" hat nach dict.com (http://www.dict.cc/?s=such+that) folgende deutsche Übersetzung:

> derart**,** dass

Nach dem Duden ist "so" ein Synonym zu "derart".

Es sind also tatsächlich die Varianten 1 und 2 richtig.

Comment: Komisch, dass jeder deutsche Mathematiker das anders sieht als Duden und dict.com.

Comment: @Uwe: Im Gegensatz zu dir habe ich Quellen angegeben.

Comment: Ganz im Gegensatz zu Dir gehe ich nicht davon aus, dass allgemeinsprachliche Worterbücher sämtliche fachsprachlichen Bedeutungen eines Wortes
widergeben.

Comment: "derart, dass" bzw. "so, dass" ist nicht nur in der Fachsprache anzutreffen.

Comment: Mir ist schon klar, dass die meisten Mathematiker ", sodass" oder ", so dass" benutzen. Aber das heißt nicht, dass sie es korrekt machen.

Comment: Kennst Du das Gefühl, wenn Dir auf der Autobahn tausende von
Geisterfahrern entgegenkommen?

Comment: Nochmal: Wenn Du das Wort "so" betonst, dann ist "so, dass" richtig. Das macht man allerdings
bei dem oben angegebenen Beispiel üblicherweise nicht.

Comment: Der Satz "Es gibt ein a in A derart, dass f(a) = b." ist korrekt. Stimmst du mir da zu? Wenn ja, dann musst du nur noch akzeptieren, dass "so" ein Synonym zu "derart" ist :-D

Comment: Mit einem betonten "derart", ja. Das kann man dann auch durch ein betontes "so" ersetzen. Ist aber in diesem Kontext unüblich. Anders sieht es z.B. aus bei "Wähle nun für jedes a_i ein a_{i+1} so, dass a_{i+1} aus X(a_i) ist." Da betont man "so" und darum steht das Komma danach. Noch anders gesagt: engl. "such that" -> dt. ", so dass", engl. "in such a way that" -> dt. "so, dass".