# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "... , so dass" und "so, dass"?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

Die folgende [Seite](https://www.jmilne.org/math/words.html) thematisiert den Unterschied zwischen "so that" und "such that" im Englischen. Am Ende wird behauptet, dass der Unterschied im Englischen mit zwei Formulierungen im Deutschen korrespondieren würde. Als Beispiel werden die folgenden beiden Sätze genannt:

> Sei x in Q, so daß es ein m in Z∖{0} mit xm in Z gibt.

> Sei y in Q so, daß 3y in Z liegt.

Mir will aber nicht so recht einleuchten, was genau der semantische Unterschied zwischen den beiden Formulierungen ist. Sieht jemand einen Unterschied und wenn, worin besteht er? Gibt es ggf. Beispiele, die den Unterschied deutlicher zeigen?

Comment: Related, in English: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30013/3237

Comment: Die ganze Verwirrung kommt daher, daß man Komposita auseinanderschreibt ("aus einander schreibt"), die zusammengehören. Klar kann man "sodaß" als "so daß" schreiben, aber dann braucht man eben vier Antworten voller Rätselraten, um das überflüssige Spatium zu erklären. Zwischen "viel versprechend" und "vielversprechend" ist eben ein Unterschied und während es "so, daß" gibt, ist "so daß" ist nicht einmal das erste, geschweige denn das zweite. Vielleicht sollten wir alle zu Desperanto (am besten mit englischem Akzent) wechseln, weil Deutsch "irgend wie über flüssig" ist.

Comment: @bakunin Eventuell ist das Komposita schon der Fehler. Wozu braucht man ein "sodass", wenn man ein "damit" hat? Allerdings kommt mir gerade die Befürchtung, "damit" könne auch ein Komposita sein.

Comment: @ceving: zwischen "sodaß" und "damit" ist ein Unterschied: "Er schlug auf den Tisch, sodaß es schepperte" drückt nicht unbedingt aus, daß das Scheppern der beabsichtigte Effekt war, während stattdessen "damit" das sehr wohl tut.

Answer (score 3):

Das Beispiel ist so gewählt, dass man es versteht, wenn man die Mathematik darin versteht.

> Sei x in Q, so dass es ein m in Z∖{0} mit xm in Z gibt.

Jede Zahl, die in Q ist (Q = Menge der Zahlen, die sich als Bruch zweier ganzer Zahlen schreiben lassen (rationale Zahlen)) erfüllt immer die Aussage, die nach "so dass" steht. Das *m* ist der Nenner des Bruchs, als der sich die Zahl schreiben lässt. Das Produkt *xm* ist der Zähler des Bruches. Z ist die Menge der ganzen Zahlen.

Das heißt, wenn die Zahl in Q ist, dann *folgt daraus immer* auch, dass die Aussage "Es gibt ein m in Z∖{0} mit xm in Z" stimmt. Der Nebensatz mit "so dass" beschreibt eine Konsequenz (Konsekutivsatz).

Anders im zweiten Beispiel:

> Sei y in Q so, dass 3y in Z liegt.

"... so, dass..." bedeutet, dass y nicht jede beliebige Zahl sein darf, sondern es darf nur Werte annehmen, die die Bedingung "3y liegt in Z" erfüllen. Zum Beispiel darf y = 1 sein, aber nicht 0,5. Der dass-Satz beschreibt also eine Bedingung, eine Qualität von y, so wie im Englischen bei "such that".

Deutschsprachige Mathematiker haben allerdings ähnlich schlechte Gewohnheiten wie englischsprachige. "So dass" wird in Deutschen auch oft anstelle von "so, dass" benutzt. Dadurch wird die Unterscheidung zwischen beiden, die in dem Artikel behauptet wird, auch im Deutschen unscharf.

Comment: Ok ich glaube ich habe es verstanden. Wenn ich sage "ich gehe so zeitig los, dass ich den Buss nicht verpasse" dann drücke ich damit meine Absicht aus, den Zeitpunkt so zu wählen, damit ich den Buss nicht verpasse. Wenn ich sage "ich gehe zeitig los, so dass ich den Buss nicht verpasse" ist ausschlossen, dass ich den Buss verpasse, weil ich zeitig losgegangen bin. Der zweite Satz lässt dann aber irgendwie offen, warum der Zeitpunkt des Losgehens zeitig war. Und ich glaube den zweiten Satz würden "Normalos" nie sagen. Der ist schon sehr mathematisch angehaucht.

Comment: Nein, beide Formulierungen kommen vor. Ich halte die zweite sogar für häufiger.

Answer (score 1):

Der Satz mit "Komma so-dass" gibt eine Folge an. "A, so dass B" heißt "B ergab sich, weil A".
Ein "so" im Hauptsatz gibt eine Eigenschaft, Art-und-Weise oder einen Grad an. Der "dass"-Satz gibt dann einen Sachverhalt, der zu dieser Eigenschaft korrespondiert. Deinen Beispielsatz versteh ich allerdings nicht, weil ich die Mathematik darin nicht verstehe :) Aber ein anderes Beispiel: "(A) Der Fisch war so groß, (B) dass zwei Mann ihn herausziehen mussten": Der Sachverhalt in B ist bedingt nicht durch die Tatsache, dass A geschehen ist (das ist auch kein Geschehnis), sondern durch den Grad der Eigenschaft, die dort genannt ist.

Zur Mathematik im Beispiel vermute ich mal, dass der zweite Satz im Grunde meint "so ein y", "das y hat eine bestimmte Eigenschaft"... Hingegen im ersten Satz "x ist in Q, und deswegen..."

Answer (score 1):

*So dass* heißt, dass aus dem ersten Teil der zweite automatisch folgt. Wenn P die Menge aller Primzahlen ist, kann ich sagen »sei x ∊ P, so dass x weniger als drei Teiler hat« (vielleicht weil ich genau diese Eigenschaft jetzt ausnutzen will).

*So, dass* bedeutet, ich wähle Elemente mit einer bestimmten Eigenschaft aus, z.B. »sei x ∊ P so, dass x die Quersumme 10 hat«. »So dass« wäre hier falsch, weil nicht alle Primzahlen diese Quersumme haben.

Answer (score 0):

Beides sind konsekutive Subjunktionen.

Allerdings ist das *so* im ersten Teilsatz nicht nur ein Korrelat, sondern ebenfalls ein Gradpartikel, in deinem Beispiel fehlt der Bezug, und ist daher so nicht nutzbar.

> Ich schreibe so schnell, dass meine Finger glühen.
> Ich schreibe schnell, sodass bzw. so dass meine Finger glühen.
> Ich schreibe, sodass bzw. so dass meine Finger glühen.
> *Ich schreibe so, dass meine Finger glühen.

Beide Sätze bedeuten dasselbe: daraus, dass ich schnell schreibe, folgt, dass meine Finger glühen.

Comment: Die bedeuten nicht dasselbe. Der erste Satz bestimmt ein Tempo anhand der Konsequenzen die das hat, der zweite Satz dient nicht zur näheren Bestimmung eines Tempos.